# Nativescript install error: trying old xmlbuilder version?

Tags: nativescript, nvm

I'm trying to install nativescript on Windows 10 using Node 4.5.0 and am getting an error.  Apparently it's trying to install version 2.2.1 of xmlbuilder (from 2014) which requires node 0.8 or 0.10.

From what I can see it's trying to install an `npm` node module?  I don't know how to debug what's going on.  Could it be something to do with nvm?

```
58355 info install write-file-atomic@1.1.4
58356 info postinstall write-file-atomic@1.1.4
58357 info install npm@2.15.9
58358 info postinstall npm@2.15.9
58359 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\npm-2b9ada4a148d9bea.lock for C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\npm
58360 verbose about to build C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\nativescript
58361 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\nativescript-a3c660f576f1098e.lock for C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\nativescript
58362 verbose stack Error: Unsupported
58362 verbose stack     at checkEngine (C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v4.5.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-install-checks\index.js:16:16)
58362 verbose stack     at Array.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v4.5.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\bind-actor.js:15:8)
58362 verbose stack     at LOOP (C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v4.5.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:15:14)
58362 verbose stack     at chain (C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v4.5.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\slide\lib\chain.js:20:5)
58362 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v4.5.0\node_modules\npm\lib\install.js:1038:5
58362 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v4.5.0\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\locker.js:39:7
58362 verbose stack     at cb (C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v4.5.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\lockfile\lockfile.js:149:38)
58362 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v4.5.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\lockfile\lockfile.js:171:16
58362 verbose stack     at C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v4.5.0\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:43:10
58362 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
58363 verbose pkgid xmlbuilder@2.2.1
58364 verbose cwd C:\Users\Jason
58365 error Windows_NT 10.0.10586
58366 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "-g" "nativescript"
58367 error node v4.5.0
58368 error npm  v2.15.9
58369 error code ENOTSUP
58370 error notsup Unsupported
58370 error notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: xmlbuilder@2.2.1
58370 error notsup Required: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"}
58370 error notsup Actual:   {"npm":"2.15.9","node":"4.5.0"}
58371 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same setup (Win-10 with node.js 4.5 and npm 2.15.9) and everything is working as expected - the NativeScript is installing from npm with no hassle.

You can try [this windows node manager](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases) in order to exclude a local incompatibility with node version. With nvm you can install several nodejs version and swith within them.

For example:

```
nvm install 4.4.7
```

Will install the previous stable version and with `nvm use 4.4.7` you can try to install nativescritp again and see if the error is still present.

You can also try

```
npm cache clean
```

Which will clean your entire npm cache [as discussed here](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/2400#issuecomment-229945915).